# How to get request origin in nodejs (expressjs)

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I hava a firebase functions based on nodejs, I used express app for to create a complex api in a single firebase function, like this:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }))

app.get('/:appId/posts/:id', (request:any, response:any) => {

    var origin = request.get('Origin'); // null
    var origin2 = request.header('Origin'); // null
    var origin3 = request.get('origin'); // null
    var origin4 = request.header('origin'); // null
    var origin5 = request.get('referer'); // null
    var origin6 = request.get('host'); // null

});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I need get the request origin, the business logic depend on it.

So, the question is: How get the request origin?

Comment: @Subburaj, yes, I did.

Comment: @victorpacheco3107 can you cross check whether you are passing `origin`

Comment: `request.get('host');` ???

Comment: @DeepakMallah, how I do it?

Comment: @Subburaj, yes, I test it, same result.

Comment: Can you try printing all headers using `req.headers` or `request` object itself? And check what you see?

Answer (score 0):

just chechk request headers first,

```
 console.log(req.headers);
```

if the output contains origin or host then:

```
console.log(req.headers.origin); or
console.log(req.headers.host);
```

(it works on me)

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    let host = socket.handshake.headers.origin
    ...
```